# How to drag from file explorer in thumbnail view

Tags: nautilus, filemanager

When I am in the file list view I can drag to other applications like desktop, slack, etc.

But when I am in thumbnail view I can't do that.

[image]

Any way to change that behavior?

File explorer doesn't say what product it is but when i search for nautilus this seems to be it.

Comment: I tried dolphin file explorer but it doesn't seem to have a thumbnail view, just icon and list detail views.

Answer (score 1):

I found that nemo does this.
I then created a shortcut by dragging nemo over the the icon launcher dock.
Its the one after Chrome in the second image below.

[image]

Shortcut:

[image]

Comment: And Caja will do what you want too :)